# Is it possible to render/generate pdf in rails without using a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

There are some gems which can generate pdf. But I don't want to use a gem. I tried the following:

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.pdf
    end
end
```

And for the link:

```
link_to show_path(@show, format: :pdf)
```

I can get the pdf output but it says the pdf document might not be displayed properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails does not generate pdf out-of-the box. PDF is a 7-bit text format with binary parts, so technically you can generate it manually using ERB-templates, `show.pdf.erb`:

```
%PDF-1.1
%¥±ë

1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R >>
endobj

2 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1 /MediaBox [0 0 300 300] >>
endobj

3 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R
    /Resources
     << /Font
         << /F1
            << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Times-Roman >>
         >>
     >>
    /Contents 4 0 R
  >>
endobj

4 0 obj << /Length 90 >>
  stream
    BT
      /F1 18 Tf
      90 150 Td
      (Hello World!) Tj
    ET
  endstream
endobj

trailer << /Root 1 0 R /Size 4 >>
%%EOF
```

This minimal PDF is viewable by some apps, but has errors in it, because there's no `xref` section and object bytecounts will be wrong. Also once you need anything more complex than single page with couple text labels on it - it will become hard to maintain.

Better way of generation is actually using a gem like prawn or wicked_pdf